# What is the SetHorspool string searching algorithm and how is it implemented?

Tags: algorithms, strings, string-matching, pseudocode, exact-string-matching

What is the SetHorspool string searching algorithm with pseudo-code so it can be easily implemented in a language of choice?

This has been implemented in 2 libraries I have come across:

- https://app-db.com/seqan/1.3/SPEC_Set_Horspool.html,
- http://stringsearchalgorithms.amygdalum.net/.

But there seem to be very little details of the algorithm available online to understand its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reading the source code](https://github.com/almondtools/stringsearchalgorithms/blob/master/src/main/java/net/amygdalum/stringsearchalgorithms/search/chars/SetHorspool.java) we can see that it is an extension of Horspool to find a match from a set of needle strings $S$, rather than matching a single needle string.

How it works is by representing the set $S$ as a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). This allows you to efficiently check character by character whether starting at position $i$ any of the strings on the trie can be found in the haystack. And like in Boyer–Moore–Horspool, if a position $i$ of the haystack fails to match any of the strings in $S$, instead of simply trying $i' = i+1$, a smarter skip lookup table is used: $i' = i + T[\text{haystack}[i + |\text{needle}| - 1]]$.

The second difference is how $T$ is computed. Normally the pseudocode is as follows (from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm)):

```
function preprocess(pattern)
    T ← new table of |Σ| integers
    for i from 0 to |Σ| exclusive
        T[i] ← length(pattern)
    for i from 0 to length(pattern) - 1 exclusive
        T[pattern[i]] ← length(pattern) - 1 - i
    return T
```

But in SetHorspool, the minimum safe skip considering all patterns is computed instead:

```
function preprocess(S)
    T ← new table of |Σ| integers
    for i from 0 to |Σ| exclusive
        T[i] ← min(length(pattern) : pattern ∈ S)
    for pattern in S
        for i from 0 to length(pattern) - 1 exclusive
            T[pattern[i]] ← min(T[pattern[i]], length(pattern) - 1 - i)
    return T
```

Comment: +1. Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to add pseudo-code on how Tire has been generated and the smart skip table if it is not inconvenient?

Comment: @SumindaSirinathS.Dharmasena The smart skip table is already in the post, the rest is simply standard tries and Horspool.